# Как JavaScript обрабатывает promise?

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise

Шлём запрос, полученный обработчик срабатывает после получения ответа:

```
var promise = ajax(...);
...
promise.then((realdata) => {...}).fail((err) => {...});
```

А если AJAX-запросы посылаются, а обработки предыдущих ещё не совершались,
всё пропадает?
Как работает `Promiz.js`?

Comment: Там не fail, а catch. Работает асинхронно, то есть функция, возвращает объект типа Promise, который запустит код из .then или .catch. Управление переходит к следующей строке не дожидаясь окончания выполнения всех then/catch блоков. Вы можете одновременно иметь столько промисов, сколько сочтёте нужным. Также рекомендую ознакомиться с async/await синтаксисом

Comment: Спасибо @DanielKhoroshko.

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Кстати, можно собрать много промисов в массив (скажем, несколько ajax запросов), и в ситуации, когда нужно дождать выполнения всех запросов: `Promise.all(promises).then..`, или любого первого запроса: `Promise.race(promises).then...` Ещё есть библиотека bluebird (и другие) расширяющие возможности промисов, правда они скорее больше для ноды, чем для браузера. Удачи

Comment: Спасибо @DanielKhoroshko. Если запросы идут так часто, что не успевает обрабатываться предыдущий, то на каждый запрос имеется свой экземпляр функции обработки? Я же не знаю, сколько у меня промисов может быть в скобках Promise.all(promises)?

Comment: В общем вот пример https://jsfiddle.net/6Lq23br5/ , в конце можно заменить .all на .race ,  увидите разницу. Кстати, нет гарантии в какой последовательности выполнятся промисы, в данном случае работает по порядку, но это просто потому что быстрый интернет

Comment: (Не забудьте открыть консоль)

Comment: Большое Спасибо @DanielKhoroshko. Насчёт последовательности исполнения - сам видел в консоли как они шли - как угодно...Там у меня ещё на сервере Laravel выдаёт такое ... если один запрос на другой наезжает...  Да, посмотрел jsfiddle. По-другому делать и не думал, если придётся. Трудно что-то придумать, если поток запросов непредсказуем (исходит от пользователя...).